# Fix "jump" when creating sticky scroll navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Sticky Navbar "jumps"

I recently made a navbar that sticks on the top of the screen when scrolling (it starts at the middle when entering the webpage). I did this on a mac and everything works just fine. However, when entering the webpage on my windows desktop, the whole navbar either jumps, skipping some content, or glitches, making me unable to scroll further down.

1) Is it the difference between macOS/windows, or safari/chrome, that makes this happen?

2) How do I fix it?

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {stickyNavbar()};
// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("navbar");
// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;
// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. 
// Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function stickyNavbar() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky ) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    background-image: url(resources/navbar.png);
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
}

.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
}

section {
   height: 1000px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  
<body>
    <img class="header-image" src="resources/header.PNG" alt="">
    <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <div><a href="pages/gallery.html">Galleri</a></div>
        <div class="active"><a href="index.html"><img class="boat-logo" src="resources/logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
        <div><a href="pages/timeline.html">Historikk</a></div>
    </nav>

    <section class="content"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: Please use runnable examples whenever you can, makes it a lot easier for others to help. I did that for you this time

Comment: A typical issue with this kind of set-up is that you are triggering your `stickyNavbar` function on each scroll event. The scroll event fires many times per scroll. As an example, scrolling my mouse wheel only slightly (let's say 100px), an event is triggered 30 times. You can imagine that when someone scrolls down, and the calculation for the navbar function needs to be called 3000 times, that's no joke. Typically, you'd use the concept of polling or event delay which I suggest you look up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position: sticky` all the time, then there's no need to to listen to the scroll event or calculate dimensions and offset, let the browser do it for you.

```css
.navbar{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    background-image: url(resources/navbar.png);
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
}

.sticky{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
}

section {
   height: 1000px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  
<body>
    <img class="header-image" src="resources/header.PNG" alt="">
    <nav class="navbar sticky" id="navbar">
        <div><a href="pages/gallery.html">Galleri</a></div>
        <div class="active"><a href="index.html"><img class="boat-logo" src="resources/logo.png" alt=""></a></div>
        <div><a href="pages/timeline.html">Historikk</a></div>
    </nav>

    <section class="content"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know this was already a property of sticky, but should have guessed judging by the name;)

Comment: Thank you! The most smooth, resource-free solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same problem if you change position to sticky?

```
sticky{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
}



window.onscroll = function() {stickyNavbar()};
// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("navbar");
// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = window.scrollY + header.getBoundingClientRect().top;
// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. 
Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function stickyNavbar() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky ) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

You could also use a debounce function so it will pasue for a bit before calculating.  It great for performance as well:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: When using "live server" plugin in VS code, changing position to sticky worked both in chrome and safari. However, when uploading the code to my webpage, it still "jumped" in chrome. Should I use another method than live server when developing the webpage?

Comment: @nikord Bizarre.  Do you have a live example?  I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "jumped".  My guess too, is look at your conditional.  It could be when it gets around the stick var it could be bouncing back and forth between if and else.  Instead of using offSet you could use HTMLElement.getBoundingClientRect().  I'll update my answer.